# How to limit the 'User Data' size of Firefox Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, cache

The User Data of Firefox Android goes on increasing every day..
To reduce it, I have to clear storage data and personalize all the settings once again after every few days.

I have set it to clear cache and everything at the closing of browser window, still the User Data goes on increasing few hundreds of MB.

The desktop version allows user to reduce the cache size but android FF doesn't seem to have any direct option.
Is there way to limit it through about:config or through any other way?

I don't use many add-ons; just 2 add-ons, AdBlockPlus and HTTPSEerywhere.

I am using Firefox 68.3.0